# Ошибка:  unsuccessful metadata update\n  Name longer than database column size'

Tags: python, база-данных, firebird, sql

Я написал следующую программу

```
import kinterbasdb
import os
import json,sqlite3,sql
con = sqlite3.connect('borey.db')
sampling_tables=con.cursor()
sampling_fields=con.cursor()
sampling_constraints=con.cursor()
sampling_constraints_fields=con.cursor()
sampling_indices=con.cursor()
sampling_indices_fields=con.cursor()
sampling_indices_props=con.cursor()
js=[]

sampling_tables.execute(sql.sqltables)

for table in sampling_tables:
    tabledict=dict(inform_about_table='?', fields='?', constraints='?', indices='?')
    information_about_table_dict=dict(name=table[1], description=table[2], can_add=table[3], can_edit=table[4], can_delete=table[5])
    #print(js_information_about_table)
    tabledict['inform_about_table']=information_about_table_dict
    #print(tabledict)
    table_id=table[0]
    sampling_fields.execute(sql.sqlfields,(table_id,))
    listfields=[]
    for field in sampling_fields:
        fielddict=dict(position=field[0], name=field[1], description=field[2], datatype=field[3], char_length=field[4], can_input=field[5], can_edit=field[6], show_in_grid=field[7],
                      is_mean=field[8], autocalculated=field[9], required=field[10])
        listfields.append(fielddict)
    tabledict['fields']=listfields
    #print(tabledict)
    sampling_constraints.execute(sql.sqlconstraints,(table_id,))
    listconstraints=[]
    for constraint in sampling_constraints:
        constraintdict=dict(name=constraint[1], constrtype=constraint[2], items='?')
        sampling_constraints_fields.execute(sql.sql_constr_det,(constraint[0],table_id))
        listitems=[]
        for constr_det in sampling_constraints_fields:
            listitems.append(constr_det[0])
        constraintdict['items']=listitems
        listconstraints.append(constraintdict)
    tabledict['constraints']=listconstraints
    #print(tabledict)
    sampling_indices.execute(sql.sqlindices,(table_id,))
    listindices=[]
    for index in sampling_indices:
        indexdict=dict(name=index[1], items='?', position='?', props='?')
        index_id=index[0]
        sampling_indices_fields.execute(sql.sql_indices_fields,(table_id,index_id))
        #sampling_indices_props.execute(sql.sql_indices_descend,(table_id,index_id, ))
        listfields=[]
        listpositions=[]
        listprops=[]
        for index_det in sampling_indices_fields:
            listfields.append(index_det[0])
            listpositions.append(index_det[1])
            fieldinindex=index_det[0]
        sampling_indices_props.execute(sql.sql_indices_descend,(table_id,index_id,fieldinindex))            
        for index_desc in sampling_indices_props:
            listprops.append(index_desc[0])
        indexdict['items']=listfields
        indexdict['position']=listpositions
        indexdict['props']=listprops
        listindices.append(indexdict)
    tabledict['indices']=listindices
    #print(tabledict)
    js.append(tabledict)
os.remove('D:/ThirdTask/test.fdb')
con=kinterbasdb.create_database("create database 'D:/ThirdTask/test.fdb' user 'sysdba' password 'masterkey'")
conn=kinterbasdb.connect(host='localhost',database='D:/ThirdTask/test.fdb', user='sysdba', password='masterkey')
cur=conn.cursor()
for nametable in js:
    s=''
    s+='create table '+nametable['inform_about_table']['name']+'\n'
    s+='('+'\n'
    countfield=0
    for namefield in nametable['fields']:
        s+='   '
        if (namefield['name'].count(' ')!=0) or (namefield['name'].count('-')!=0) or (namefield['name'].count('/')!=0):
            s+='"'+namefield['name']+'"'
        else:
            if namefield['name']=='COUNT':
                s+='QUANTITY'
            else:
                s+=namefield['name']
        if namefield['datatype']=='FMTBCD':
            s+='   '+' INTEGER NOT NULL'
        else:
            if namefield['datatype']=='STRING': 
                s+='   '+'VARCHAR'
            else:
                if namefield['datatype']=='MEMO':
                    s+='   '+'BLOB SUB_TYPE 1'
                else:            
                    if namefield['datatype']=='LARGEINT':
                        s+='   '+'BIGINT'
                    else:
                        if namefield['datatype']=='CURRENCY':
                            s+='   '+'NUMERIC(18,2)'
                        else:    
                            s+='   '+namefield['datatype']           
        if namefield['datatype']=='STRING':
            s+='('+str(namefield['char_length'])+')'
        countfield+=1
        #if countfield!=len(nametable['fields']):
        s+=','+'\n'
        #else:
            #s+='\n'
            #s+='\n'
    for nameconstraint in nametable['constraints']:
        if nameconstraint['constrtype']=='PRIMARY':
            s+='   CONSTRAINT '+nameconstraint['name']+ ' PRIMARY KEY('
            countfieldinconstr=0
            for namefield in nameconstraint['items']:
                countfieldinconstr+=1
                if countfieldinconstr!=len(nameconstraint['items']):
                        if (namefield.count(' ')!=0) or (namefield.count('-')!=0) or (namefield.count('/')!=0):
                            s+='"'+namefield+'"'+','
                        else:
                            if namefield=='COUNT':
                                s+='QUANTITY'+','
                            else:    
                                s+=namefield+','
                else:
                        if (namefield.count(' ')!=0) or (namefield.count('-')!=0) or (namefield.count('/')!=0):
                            s+='"'+namefield+'"'+')'+'\n'
                        else:
                            if namefield=='COUNT':
                                s+='QUANTITY'+')'+'\n'
                            else:       
                                s+=namefield+')'+'\n'
    s+=');'+'\n'
    print s
    cur.execute(s)
    conn.commit()
    for nameindex in nametable['indices']:
        #print 'nameidex[props] ', nameindex['props']
        s=''
        for prop in nameindex['props']:
            if prop==0:
                if (nameindex['name'].count(' ')!=0) or (nameindex['name'].count('-')!=0) or (nameindex['name'].count('/')!=0):
                    s+='create ascending index "'+nameindex['name'] + '" on '+nametable['inform_about_table']['name']+' ('
                else:
                    s+='create ascending index '+nameindex['name'] + ' on '+nametable['inform_about_table']['name']+' ('
            countitem=0
            for nameitem in nameindex['items']:
                if countitem!=len(nameindex['items'])-1:
                        if (nameitem.count(' ')!=0) or (nameitem.count('-')!=0) or (nameitem.count('/')!=0):
                            s+='"'+nameitem+'"'+', '
                        else:
                            if nameitem=='COUNT':
                                s+='QUANTITY'+', '
                            else:  
                                s+=nameitem+', '
                else:
                        if (nameitem.count(' ')!=0) or (nameitem.count('-')!=0) or (nameitem.count('/')!=0):
                            s+='"'+nameitem+'"'+');'+'\n'
                        else:
                            if nameitem=='COUNT':
                                s+='QUANTITY'+');'+'\n'
                            else:  
                                s+=nameitem+');'+'\n'
        print s
        cur.execute(s)
        conn.commit()
s="""
create table CLIENTS
(
   ID   INTEGER NOT NULL,
   COMPANY   VARCHAR(50),
   "LAST NAME"   VARCHAR(50),
   "FIRST NAME"   VARCHAR(50),
   "E-MAIL ADDRESS"   VARCHAR(50),
   "JOB TITLE"   VARCHAR(50),
   "BUSINESS PHONE"    VARCHAR(25),
   "HOME PHONE"   VARCHAR(25),
   "MOBILE PHONE"   VARCHAR(25),
   "FAX NUMBER"   VARCHAR(25),
   ADDRESS   BLOB SUB_TYPE 1,
   CITY   VARCHAR(50),
   "STATE/PROVINCE"   VARCHAR(50),
   "ZIP/POSTAL CODE"   VARCHAR(15),
   "COUNTRY/REGION"   VARCHAR(50),
   "WEB-SITE"   VARCHAR(25),
   NOTES   BLOB SUB_TYPE 1,
   INCLUDING   BLOB
);
"""
s1='create ascending index IDX_CLIENTS_CITY on CLIENTS (CITY);'
#print s
#cur.execute(s)
#conn.commit()
#cur.execute(s1)
#conn.commit()
#cur=con.cursor()
con.close()
conn.close()
print "Connect succesfully"
```

Выдает следующую ошибку

```
create table CLIENTS
(
   ID    INTEGER NOT NULL,
   COMPANY   VARCHAR(50),
   "LAST NAME"   VARCHAR(50),
   "FIRST NAME"   VARCHAR(50),
   "E-MAIL ADDRESS"   VARCHAR(50),
   "JOB TITLE"   VARCHAR(50),
   "BUSINESS PHONE"   VARCHAR(25),
   "HOME PHONE"   VARCHAR(25),
   "MOBILE PHONE"   VARCHAR(25),
   "FAX NUMBER"   VARCHAR(25),
   ADDRESS   BLOB SUB_TYPE 1,
   CITY   VARCHAR(50),
   "STATE/PROVINCE"   VARCHAR(50),
   "ZIP/POSTAL CODE"   VARCHAR(15),
   "COUNTRY/REGION"   VARCHAR(50),
   "WEB-SITE"   VARCHAR(25),
   NOTES   BLOB SUB_TYPE 1,
   INCLUDING   BLOB,
   CONSTRAINT PK_CLIENTS_ID PRIMARY KEY(ID)
);

create ascending index IDX_CLIENTS_CITY on CLIENTS (CITY);

create ascending index IDX_CLIENTS_COMPANY on CLIENTS (COMPANY);

create ascending index IDX_CLIENTS_FIRST_NAME on CLIENTS ("FIRST NAME");

create ascending index IDX_CLIENTS_LAST_NAME on CLIENTS ("LAST NAME");

create ascending index IDX_CLIENTS_POSTAL_CODE on CLIENTS ("ZIP/POSTAL CODE");

create ascending index IDX_CLIENTS_PRIMARYKEY on CLIENTS (ID);

create ascending index "IDX_CLIENTS_STATE/PROVINCE" on CLIENTS ("STATE/PROVINCE");

create table EMPLOYEES
(
   ID    INTEGER NOT NULL,
   COMPANY   VARCHAR(50),
   "LAST NAME"   VARCHAR(50),
   "FIRST NAME"   VARCHAR(50),
   "E-MAIL ADDRESS"   VARCHAR(50),
   "JOB TITLE"   VARCHAR(50),
   "BUSINESS PHONE"   VARCHAR(25),
   "HOME PHONE"   VARCHAR(25),
   "MOBILE PHONE"   VARCHAR(25),
   "FAX NUMBER"   VARCHAR(25),
   ADDRESS   BLOB SUB_TYPE 1,
   CITY   VARCHAR(50),
   "STATE/PROVINCE"   VARCHAR(50),
   "ZIP/POSTAL CODE"   VARCHAR(15),
   "COUNTRY/REGION"   VARCHAR(50),
   "WEB-SITE"   VARCHAR(25),
   NOTES   BLOB SUB_TYPE 1,
   INCLUDING   BLOB,
   CONSTRAINT PK_EMPLOYEES_ID PRIMARY KEY(ID)
);

create ascending index IDX_EMPLOYEES_CITY on EMPLOYEES (CITY);

create ascending index IDX_EMPLOYEES_COMPANY on EMPLOYEES (COMPANY);

create ascending index IDX_EMPLOYEES_FIRST_NAME on EMPLOYEES ("FIRST NAME");

create ascending index IDX_EMPLOYEES_LAST_NAME on EMPLOYEES ("LAST NAME");

create ascending index IDX_EMPLOYEES_POSTAL_CODE on EMPLOYEES ("ZIP/POSTAL CODE");

create ascending index IDX_EMPLOYEES_PRIMARYKEY on EMPLOYEES (ID);

create ascending index "IDX_EMPLOYEES_STATE/PROVINCE" on EMPLOYEES ("STATE/PROVINCE");

create table ORDERS
(
   ORDERID    INTEGER NOT NULL,
   EMPLOYEEID   BIGINT,
   CLIENTID   BIGINT,
   "PLACEMENT DATE"   DATE,
   "SHIPMENT DATE"   DATE,
   "CONSIGNOR ID"   BIGINT,
   RECEIVER   VARCHAR(50),
   "RECEIVER ADDRESS"   BLOB SUB_TYPE 1,
   "RECEIVER CITY"   VARCHAR(50),
   "RECEIVER STATE"   VARCHAR(50),
   "DELIVERY INDEX"   VARCHAR(50),
   "DELIVERY COUNTRY/REGION"   VARCHAR(40),
   "DELIVERY COST"   NUMERIC(18,2),
   TAXES   NUMERIC(18,2),
   "PAYMENT TYPE"   VARCHAR(30),
   "PAYMENT DATE"   DATE,
   NOTES   BLOB SUB_TYPE 1,
   "TAX RATE"   FLOAT,
   "TAX STATUS"   SMALLINT,
   "ID STATUS"   SMALLINT,
   CONSTRAINT PK_ORDERS_ID PRIMARY KEY(ORDERID)
);

create ascending index IDX_ORDERS_CUSTOMERID on ORDERS (CLIENTID);

create ascending index IDX_ORDERS_CUSTOMERONORDERS on ORDERS (CLIENTID);

create ascending index IDX_ORDERS_EMPLOYEEID on ORDERS (EMPLOYEEID);

create ascending index IDX_ORDERS_EMPLOYEESONORDERS on ORDERS (EMPLOYEEID);

create ascending index IDX_ORDERS_ORDERSID on ORDERS (ORDERID);

create ascending index IDX_ORDERS_ORDERSTATUS on ORDERS ("ID STATUS");

create ascending index IDX_ORDERS_PRIMARYKEY on ORDERS (ORDERID);

create ascending index IDX_ORDERS_SHIPPERID on ORDERS ("CONSIGNOR ID");

create ascending index IDX_ORDERS_SHIPPERONORDER on ORDERS ("CONSIGNOR ID");

create ascending index IDX_ORDERS_STATUS_ID on ORDERS ("ID STATUS");

create ascending index IDX_ORDERS_TAXSTATUSONORDERS on ORDERS ("TAX STATUS");

create ascending index IDX_ORDERS_ZIP_POSTALCODE on ORDERS ("DELIVERY INDEX");

create table INFORMATION_ABOUT_ORDER
(
   ID    INTEGER NOT NULL,
   ORDERID   BIGINT,
   PRODUCTID   BIGINT,
   QUANTITY   FLOAT,
   PRICEFORUNIT   NUMERIC(18,2),
   DISCOUNT   FLOAT,
   "ID STATUS"   BIGINT,
   "PLACEMENT DATE"   DATE,
   "ORDERID FOR ACQUISITION"   BIGINT,
   "ACCESSION NUMBER"   BIGINT,
   CONSTRAINT PK_INFORMATION_ABOUT_ORDER_ID PRIMARY KEY(ID)
);

create ascending index IDX_INFORMATION_ABOUT_ORDER_ID on INFORMATION_ABOUT_ORDER (ID);

create ascending index IDX_INFORMATION_ABOUT_ORDER_INVENTORY_ID on INFORMATION_ABOUT_ORDER ("ACCESSION NUMBER");

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\ThirdTask\connect.py", line 163, in <module>
    cur.execute(s)
ProgrammingError: (-607, 'isc_dsql_execute: \n  unsuccessful metadata update\n  Name longer than database column size')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Возможно, в системной таблице не хватает размера столбца, куда записываются имена таблиц/индексов.